# client.connect() additional parameters - query

Tags: arduino, iot, esp32

I use ESP32 as client for my socket.io server application. I need ESP32 to send MAC Address as query within "connect" method. In my browser I can do:

```
io('localhost:2000', {query: { mac: 222222 }})
```

I need ESP32 to do the same thing, but I am limited to the WiFiClient library, which I can use for a basic connection to the server:

```
client.connect(host, port)
```

But I want to send additional information, for example:

```
client.connect(host, port, query)
```

Comment: `WiFiClient` is for TCP connections. There is no such thing as a query parameter. Either use a socket.io library or implement the protocol yourself.

Answer (score -1):

In order to query something, you have to prepare the HTTP request, describing it with the `println` function. You can see an example below, extracted from the [official site](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFiClient):

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

char ssid[] = "myNetwork";          //  your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "myPassword";   // your network password

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
IPAddress server(74,125,115,105);  // Google

// Initialize the client library
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Attempting to connect to WPA network...");
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  if ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't get a wifi connection");
    // don't do anything else:
    while(true);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
    Serial.println("\nStarting connection...");
    // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
    if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Make a HTTP request:
      //Here you have to mount your "query" or specify your JSON body (HTTP protocol):
      client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0"); 
      client.println();
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more examples [here](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=4612&start=20), [here (it is a POST example, but it is useful)](https://github.com/esp8266h/Arduino/issues/1390) and [here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=160470.0).